# controller not registered in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to add a controller to spring starter project, but the mapped path always return 404 error.

I first downloaded the maven project from https://start.spring.io/, then I created a controllers directory, and add a HomeController.java in src/main/java/com/example/controllers directory:

```
package com.example.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "123";
    }
}
```

And I launch the spring-boot application with `mvn spring-boot:run`, and test the /test with curl:

```
%> curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/test
{"timestamp":"2022-04-07T02:00:37.745+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/test"}
```

What's wrong with the controller?

Comment: can you share application properties file contents here? have you set context path , if yes you need to have url like
http://127.0.0.1:8080/yourcontext path/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to refer some of this link `https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/`

You need to let spring know which components need to be scanned and registered. So add `@ComponentScan("com.example.controllers")` to `DemoApplication`.

```java
@ComponentScan("com.example.controllers")
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked. I actually followed this article and it does not require a ComponentScan annotation: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. Why do I have to add a annotation?

Comment: @daisy Spring will scan `com.example.demo` and its sub packages, such as `com.example.demo.controller` and `com.example.demo.service` according to the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. But your `com.example.controllers` is not a sub package of `com.example.demo`